# Issue with displaying unit vectors

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, vector

I am using the following command to display unit vectors for my report:

```
\newcommand{\ihat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{\i}}}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{\j}}}}
```

This is my result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you give a full example, how to obtain such unexpected result, please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In proper method, which you can also see in the log. Try this (`memoir` class not related, just happens to be the basic class in my editor):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,mathtools}

\newcommand{\ihat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\ihat \quad  \jhat 
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: If you want them upright, then with the packages I used, you code should work. If not, then as usual on this site, please provide a full minimal example that we can compile and test. Sniplets like this usually does not help much

Comment: Why double `\bm`? Note that `bm.sty` redefines `\boldsymbol` to do `\bm`.

Comment: @egreg, typo. I never use `\boldsymbol`. `\bm` removed

Comment: So made your answer identical to mine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you're obtaining that strange output, but here's how you can get a (bold) hat over a bold letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\bm{\hat{\imath}}+\bm{\hat{\jmath}}+\bm{\hat{k}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Should the hat not be boldface, switch the positions of `\hat` and `\bm`:

```
\begin{equation*}
\hat{\bm{\imath}}+\hat{\bm{\jmath}}+\hat{\bm{k}}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]